# How do you swap first list element with another li element on click

Tags: javascript, html, list

i'm trying to create a menu where each time you click a link it swap's the parent "li" with the first one, can anyone tell how can i do this?

This is the initial menu:

```
    <ul class="top-menu">
    <li class="first-element"><a href="/">First</a><li>
    <li class="second-element"><a href="/">Second</a><li>
    <li class="third-element"><a href="/">Third</a><li>
    <li class="fourth-element"><a href="/">Fourth</a><li>
   </ul>
```

This is the menu after you click the fourth link:

```
    <ul class="top-menu">
  <li class="fourth-element"><a href="/">Fourth</a><li>
    <li class="second-element"><a href="/">Second</a><li>
    <li class="third-element"><a href="/">Third</a><li>
    <li class="first-element"><a href="/">First</a><li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7y26V/3/)

```
<ul class="top-menu">
    <li class="first-element">First</li>
    <li class="second-element">Second</li>
    <li class="third-element">Third</li>
    <li class="fourth-element">Fourth</li>
</ul>

$.fn.exchangePositionWith = function(selector) {
    var other = $(selector);
    this.after(other.clone());
    other.after(this).remove();
};

$(document.body).on('click', 'ul.top-menu li' ,function(){
    var pos = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $("ul.top-menu li:eq("+pos+")").exchangePositionWith("ul.top-menu li:eq(0)");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.top-menu li').live('click', function() {
     $(this).remove();
    $(this).prependTo('.top-menu');
});
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to skipped the first one.

Comment: `.live` is deprecated in the latest version of jquery

Comment: Thank you abdul wakeel, it wasn't exactly what i wanted but i've learned a new way to create a top menu.